# Application (JBoss + Hibernate + Infinispan) performance degrades on the same data

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, garbage-collection, infinispan

We have the following stack for a web application: DB + Infinispan 5.1.2 + Hibernate 3.6.9 + JBoss AS 7.1 + Seam 2.2 + RichFaces 3.3(JSF 1.2).

After application start the one page shows historical data for past period by 1-2 sec. During this rendering Hibernate session(1 level) cache contains about 8 000 objects and during the next week data were not changed (not changed at all) but performance for this page rendering degrades from 1 sec to 30-70 sec.

The jVisualVM Sampler tells about time consumed in `autoFlushIfRequired` method in the Hibernate Session object. We have around 25-30 calls of this function during rendering. All Hibernate queries were cached, all database transactions have short life age. The threads count was increased insignificantly. We have 12-50 simultaneously clients (browsers) for the application. We don't have memory leaks and have enough memory (full gc start every 10-15 minutes). The young GC time is increased constantly. Java starts with the followings args:

```
-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseLargePages -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=4m
-XX:+UseTLAB"
-Xms3092m -Xmx3092m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m  -XX:MaxNewSize=1g
-XX:NewSize=1g -XX:SurvivorRatio=128
```

During monitoring Cent OS we see that the counter "Context switch per second" (vmstat output) was increased from 1000 - 1500 to 8000 - 10000. We possibly have a problem with access synchronization in Heap/Hibernate/Infinispan? What other cases should we examine? How could it be checked?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Hibernate eventually ends up wading through all your objects to see if they are dirty. When you start the application, it doesn't have to, but the further it progresses the worse it gets.

Maybe you can try calling `flush()` manually only when you need to instead? Or implement your own custom check instead of letting Hibernate figure out what needs flushing on its own.

You can do this by implementing [the `Interceptor` interface](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html) (extend `EmptyInterceptor` if you don't want to implement all of it) with the method `findDirty` implemented to your liking. This way you can tell Hibernate to not bother with unchanged objects.

Comment: We can't explain why this happen because we have the same objects in 1-level cache on server start and since 1 week. We have another hypothesis about lazy objects: on start we don't have lazy objects in memory and Hibernate don't scan their during 'dirty checking'. When we have  Infinispan cache and lazy object loaded in it then it can give us the bigger object graph in memory

Comment: @vim Exactly, which is why it at first doesn't have to but after a while has to check more and more objects to see if they are dirty. Solution in answer.

Comment: It's not lazy objects problem because we have tried to render page with historical data several times. After the first request the cache(Infinispan) becomes warm. No degradation at second, third page rendering. Only since 2 weeks